# SELECT the patients that have similar disease name EF core 3.1

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have the following tables

1. Patients

   ```
     ID   PatientName   PatientIDNumber  
    ---- ------------- ----------------- 
      1   Jo                  411420607  
      2   Mark                206047758
   ```

1. Records

   ```
     ID    DiseaseName    PatinetID  
    ---- --------------- ----------- 
      1   Liver Disease           1  
      2   Heart Disease           1  
      3   Liver Disease           2  
      4   Heart Disease           2
   ```

Each patient has many records

- Patient Data model class

  ```
  public class PatientEntity : BaseEntity
       {
           [Column("PatientName")]
           [StringLength(150)]
           public string Name { get; set; }

           [Column("OfficialIDNumber")]
           [StringLength(10), MinLength(10)]
           public string IDNumber { get; set; }

           [Column("SystemIDnumber")]
           public int SystemID { get; set; }

           [Column("PatientDateOfBirth")]
           public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

           [Column("PatientEmailAdress")]
           [StringLength(300)]
           public string EmailAdress { get; set; }

           public IEnumerable<LookupsEntity> MetaData { get; set; }

           public IEnumerable<RecordEntity> Records { get; set; }
       }
  ```
- Record data model class

  ```
  public class RecordEntity : BaseEntity
   {
       [StringLength(50)]
       public string DiseaseName { get; set; }

       public DateTime TimeOfEntry { get; set; }

       [StringLength(300)]
       public string Description { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("Patient")]
       public int PatientId { get; set; }
       public PatientEntity Patient { get; set; }

       public BillEntity Bill { get; set; }

   }
  ```

I want to create an API that takes a specific patient id as a parameter to get a list of other patients with similar diseases

- Patient report API result (DTO)

  ```
  public class PatinetReportResource
   {
       public PatientResource patient { get; set; }
       public IList<PatientResource> SimilarPatinets { get; set; }
   }
  ```

Note: ***Similar diseases mean that the two patients have in common 2 or more disease**

How to List patients with similar diseases in EF core 3.1?

Comment: @GertArnold
Sorry, I've updated the question to include a specific details

Comment: Yeah... I mean code. It's not even clear what type of code you're working on. SQL, LINQ? That's why you should *always* show your own efforts. Clarifies more than words. (And if LINQ, which class model, which EF version?).

Comment: @GertArnold
Thank you for the feedback. 
I've included more details that show the data model classes that I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bare bones of what you need, without relying on your disease names being in the same order.

If you need additional info like `PatientName`, you can just add them in by wrapping the `select` below in a `cte` and then `join` onto the Patient data:

[As a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4916234d88ed18cb17f338bd2481cd82).

```
declare @p table(ID int,PatientName varchar(10),PatientIDNumber int);
insert into @p values
 (1,'Jo',411420607)
,(2,'Mark',206047758)
,(3,'Paul',552065834)
,(4,'Lisa',653025132);

declare @r table(ID int,DiseaseName varchar(30),PatientID int);
insert into @r values
 (1,'Liver Disease',1)
,(2,'Heart Disease',1)
,(3,'Liver Disease',2)
,(4,'Heart Disease',2)
,(5,'Liver Disease',3)
,(6,'Lung Disease',3)
,(7,'Arm Disease',4)
,(8,'Lung Disease',4)
,(9,'Liver Disease',4)
,(10,'Heart Disease',4);

declare @id int = 1;

select r.PatientID
        ,r2.PatientID as MatchedPatientID
from @r as r
    join @r as r2
        on r.DiseaseName = r2.DiseaseName
            and r.PatientID <> r2.PatientID
where r.PatientID = @id
group by r.PatientID
        ,r2.PatientID
having count(r2.PatientID) >= 2;
```

Comment: Where's EF core 3.1 in this answer?

Comment: @GertArnold The question also tagged `sql-server` which suggests that the query is being passed to a SQL backend.  As such I provided a solution that can be encapsulated within a view or table valued function or if desired, have the fairly simple query logic converted into EF by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

This addresses my interpretation of the original question.

The simplest method is string aggregation:

```
select diseases, string_agg(patientid, ',') within group (order by patientid) as patients
from (select patientId, string_agg(diseasename, ',') within group (order by diseasename) as diseases
      from t
      group by patientid
     ) p
group by diseases;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1c185a94fce074fb9d1938df09770b2e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Does this not only work if the diseases are in the same sort order?  One patient with `Heart,Liver,Lung` diseases should match another with just `Heart,Lung` per the OP, but I don't think it will in your solution?

Comment: @iamdave . . . The question has changed significantly since I answered it.

Comment: In that case should you not either change or remove your answer to avoid confusion for anyone coming to this question later on?